# AWS EC2 Launch Template: Execute bash script using cloud-config

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

My EC2 instances are configured with AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate which uses cloud-config in the UserData section of the launchtemplate.

```
UserData:
          # Parts of cloud-config file are executed in the same order. Order if fixed by cloud-init.
          # Documentation : https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html
          Fn::If:
            - DatadogAgentEnabled
            - Fn::Base64: !Sub |
                #cloud-config
                repo_update: true

                write_files:
                ......
                .......
                packages:
                  - amazon-efs-utils
                  - jq
                  - nfs-utils
              
                package_update: true
                package_upgrade: true
                 .......
                 .......
                runcmd:
                  - [ mkdir, /efs ]
                  - [ mount, /efs ]
                 .......
                 .......
```

But now I need to execute a shell script which has nearly 100 lines of code.
How I can execute the whole script under cloud-config?

**Update:**

I tried putting the script right after the Userdata as a test.
The cloudformation update was successful but the commands below cloud-config failed to execute during deployment. How I checked is: In runcmd section, I was installing codedeploy agent. but after the below update of the CFN template, I tried to launch a new instance and deployment failed.
Then I removed the sample script [mkdir /home/test] and deployment succeed.

```
UserData:
          # Parts of cloud-config file are executed in the same order. Order if fixed by cloud-init.
          # Documentation : https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html
          Fn::If:
            - DatadogAgentEnabled
            - Fn::Base64: !Sub |
                #!/bin/bash
                mkdir  /home/test
                #cloud-config
                repo_update: true
```

Comment: You could create custom AMI to have it full pre-configured with zero or little user-data required.

Comment: Thanks but is there any other way so that I can include the bash script in the launch template itself?

Comment: And what's happening if you add that 100 lines to UserData?

Comment: Its not clear what you are doing. `UserData` should be a bash script. Whatever you are providing is not a valid bash.

Comment: Can you explain a little more please?  
Below is a valid bash script I think. But where is the problem?


  #!/bin/bash
  mkdir  /home/test

Comment: For example, ` repo_update: true` is not a valid bash command.

Comment: Oh I see, I just put the script after the UserData section but above the cloud-config so that both works. May be it is not the way...Did you mean just to use the shell script and remove the cloud-config section?